# google maps reactjs polygon using kml file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I am working in google maps api "google-map-react" in reactjs and using typescript. google map is working and shows marker when i use url but not showing polygon when using file. here is the main file.

```
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";
import kmlFile from "../data/file.kml";
const GOOGLE_API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY;

export default function ShowMap2() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
      <GoogleMapReact
        style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vh" }}
        bootstrapURLKeys={{
          key: GOOGLE_API_KEY,
          libraries: ["visualization"],
        }}
        defaultCenter={{
          lat: 39.8496,
          lng: -75.2557,
        }}
        defaultZoom={5}
        yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals
        onGoogleApiLoaded={({ map, maps }: any) => {
          console.log(kmlFile);

          const kml = new maps.KmlLayer({
            url: kmlFile,
          });
          kml.setMap(map);
        }}
      ></GoogleMapReact>
    </div>
  );
}
```

there is my tsconfig file -

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

declaration.d.ts

```
declare module "*.kml" {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}

declare module "google-map-react";
```

getting /static/media/file.647c54322ab61c966d93.kml in console

also i can not find best documentation for google maps in reactjs.

Comment: Hello! Is that the full error shown in the console? Can you also please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like a codesandbox link? So that the community can check.